# How to parse a PHP project, find a function occurrences in code and detect the called parameter in each call?

Tags: php, regex, replace

Edited: The real name of the function is CB_t

Consider a project with several files and folders.
Across the project we call a CB_t($string='') function several times with different parameters.
What I need is to find programatically all the times that this functions was called and create a array with the parameters. The parameter is always a String.

Code Sample:

File 1:

```
<?php
# Some code ....

$a = CB_t('A');
$b = CB_t("B");

# more code ...
```

File 2:

```
<?php
# Some code ....

$c = CB_t("ABC");
$d = CB_t('1938');

# more code ...
```

What I need is to parse all the code and create an array with all the parameters.
I the case of the above sample the array should look like:

```
['A','B','ABC','1938']
```

Below is what I tried until now and is not giving good results because the function was sometimes called using simple quotes and sometimes using double quotes or using upper case or lowercase.

```
    $search = "F(";
    $path = realpath(ROOT); // ROOT defined as project root folder 
    $fileList = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    $count = 0;$counter = 0;
    foreach ($fileList as $item) 
    {
        if ( $item->isFile() && substr($item->getPathName(), -4) =='.php')  // #1
        {

            $counter++;

            $file = file_get_contents($item->getPathName());


                if( strpos($file,trim($search)) !== false) {

                    $count++;

                    echo "<br>File no   : ".$count;
                    echo "<br>Filename  : ".$item->getFileName();
                    echo "<br>File path : ".$item->getPathName();
                    echo "<hr>";


                } // End file is php

            unset($file);

        } // End if #1

    } // End foreach
```

I think that can solved somehow with regular expressions but I don't control this part very good.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't this the kind of thing you usually do with a good IDE?

Comment: Yes maybe a good IDE can do that but I need to do it programatically in the Backend of a site.

Comment: @vitaminasweb: **why** do you need to do this?

Comment: Something like [that](http://regex101.com/r/qU0eB9) or [that](http://regex101.com/r/bO8gD2)? I'm not sure how/where to implement it in your existing code though. Maybe replacing the innermost if block and getting the length of the array for the `$count`.

Comment: @amal-murali - It's a long story and I think that knowing what is for it will not help you to answer the question!

Comment: @jerry - My method is iterating well all the code and the ,php file detections also works well but the "if" condition  where I use "strpos" is fail because it's not detecting all the function occurrences ... strpos($file,trim($search)) !== false  -> is not good idea I need here some regex to detect the f() function even if it's called with single quotes or double quotes or using F (upcase) or f (lowcase) and the get the argument passed to the function each time ... In fact the real function name is CB_t($string='').

Answer (score 1):

This might work. Some extra annotations there for the branch reset. Capture group 1 will
contain the string content.

```
 Edit - If you want to make the regex into a C-style string, here it is:    

 "[Ff]\\s*\\(\\s*(?|\"([^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*)\"|'([^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*)')\\s*\\)"
 ---------------------------------------------------------


      #  [Ff]\s*\(\s*(?|"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)')\s*\)

      [Ff] 
      \s* 
      \(
      \s* 
      (?|
           " 
 br 1      (                              # (1 start)
                [^"\\]* 
                (?: \\ . [^"\\]* )*
    1      )                              # (1 end)
           "
        |  
           ' 
 br 1      (                              # (1 start)
                [^'\\]* 
                (?: \\ . [^'\\]* )*
    1      )                              # (1 end)
           '
      )
      \s* 
      \)
```

Edit2 - Usage example:

```
 $string =
 "
 f('hello')
 F(\"world\")
 ";

 preg_match_all
      ( 
          "/[Ff]\\s*\\(\\s*(?|\"([^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*)\"|'([^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*)')\\s*\\)/",
          $string,
          $matches,
          PREG_PATTERN_ORDER
      );
  print_r( $matches[1] );

 -----------------------------
 Result:
 Array
 (
     [0] => hello
     [1] => world
 )
```

Comment: Woww!!! I have no idea how to implement all this in PHP ... In my opinion you must be a genius to understand regular expressions ... Maybe you can make a little implementation of that or try to explain me with a more details how to do it or what part detect the function and what part detect the arguments passed to that function! Tn fact the real name of the function is CB_t($string='') where the $string is the parameter passed to the func. Thanks a lot! You are genial!

Comment: @vitaminasweb - I didn't invent this regex. Much better minds than mine put it together through the years. Its just string escaping. You can read the simple expanded regex from top to bottom, nothing there you don't already know. The only extra construct is the branch reset. And btw, I use the program from RegexFormat.com that does all the nice nice stuff with a simple button click.

Comment: Thanks ... I will try that and came back with an answer!

Comment: Hello @sln! I tried to a little with your regex code and I tried to change it to fit the real name of my function that is CB_t() and something is not working well. You can take a look [here](http://regex101.com/r/vO9zF1) I am stuck with this and I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain the regular expression is clever enough, but this should get you close:

```
foreach ($fileList as $item) 
{
    if ( $item->isFile() && substr($item->getPathName(), -4) =='.php')  // #1
    {
        $counter++;

        $file = file_get_contents($item->getPathName());
        $matches= array();

        $count= preg_match_all('/\bCB_t\s*\(\s*[\'"](.*?)[\'"]\s*\)/i', $file, $matches);

        echo "<br>File no   : ".$count;
        echo "<br>Filename  : ".$item->getFileName();
        echo "<br>File path : ".$item->getPathName();
        echo "<hr>";

        unset($file);

        $total+= $count;
    } // End if #1

} // End foreach
```

The regular expression looks for an `CB_t` (or an `cb_t` -- the i at the end makes it case-insensitive) followed by zero or more spaces followed by a `(` followed by zero or more spaces (again) followed by a single- or double-quote. (Obviously this won't match anywhere where CB_t is called with a variable parameter e.g. `CB_t($somevar)` - you'd need to tweak it for that.)

It then uses the result from a call to `preg_match_all` to count the number of matches on the page. (I've added a $total count too - I was using that in my own testing!)

One problem I know the regular expression has is it will still count a call to CB_t that appears in comments or within another string e.g.

```
/* CB_t('fred'); */
$somevar= 'CB_t("fred")';
```

Will both get counted.

Hope it helps!

(Edited for careless pasting)

(Edited again to include Galvic's improved RegExp and to change the function name as requested.)

Comment: This will also fetch all functions/methods that end with `f`, like for example `functionF("A")` or `printf('aaa')`.

Comment: Hello @danielpsc, This is very very helpful answer ... just one thing that I did't specify from the beginning is that the real name of the function is CB_t ! can You refactor the regex to do the same using this function name or I have to refactor the entire code and change the name of my function to f() ... Thanks a lot! It's make a lot of sense for me .

Comment: @glavic maybe you have some ideas about how to prevent that! Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: @Glavić - good spot, hadn't thought of that! At least it isn't as likely now the function name has changed! :)

Comment: Your [example](http://regex101.com/r/nQ2iM9). Little fix [example](http://regex101.com/r/eB5gS4).

Comment: @Glavić cool - I've included your version in the edited code above, hope that's OK! RegExp changed to change the function name as requested.

Comment: This is kinda hard to achive with regular expresion. See examples that should and are not fetch, and should't and are fetched > [here](http://regex101.com/r/fQ9oB0).

Comment: So, I should use the code above or it will fail? What you think about the code that @sln propose ? ... and Thanks again !!!